# Ionic2 how to push the page with tab from app outside

Tags: ios, cordova, angular, ionic2

[image]

I have used deeplink for social sharing[ionic deeplink plugin],when I click the  twitter share link it will redirect to corresponding page. But the tab is not appearing. I have used following code for social share.

```
 Deeplinks.routeWithNavController(this.nav, {
                '/category/:postId':'Here PageName'
                }).subscribe((match) => {
                console.log('Successfully routed', match);
                }, (nomatch) => {
                console.log('Not matched', nomatch);;
            });
```

For Nav push i have used following code

```
this.nav.push(TabsNavigationPage);
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: "But the tab is not appearing." you mean the tab bar does not show? can you put a screenshot to show what you mean?

Comment: see my edited question